# 3D object in java won't rotate properly along the x axis

Tags: java, 3d

I have recently been working on a 3D renderer in java for the first time, It works well when the user drags it along the y axis, but dragging an object along the x axis doesn't always properly rotate it relitive to the user.[image: cube example] This cube only rotates along the x axis correctly when the green side is on the top. Otherwise it will roll, or spin backwards. This is my code:

```
    package Main;
    
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Container;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.Graphics2D;
    import java.awt.Image;
    import java.awt.MouseInfo;
    import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
    import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
    import java.awt.geom.Path2D;
    import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.stream.Collectors;

    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;


    public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
    
            final int[] x = {0};
            final int[] y = {0};
    
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            Container pane = frame.getContentPane();
            pane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    
            JPanel renderPanel = new JPanel() {
    
                public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                            
                    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
                    g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                    g2.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            
                    List<Polygon> polygons = new ArrayList<>();
                    polygons.add(new Polygon(new ArrayList<>(), Color.WHITE));
                    polygons.get(0).vertices.add(new Point(100, 100, 100));
                    polygons.get(0).vertices.add(new Point(-100, 100, 100));
                    polygons.get(0).vertices.add(new Point(-100, -100, 100));
                    polygons.get(0).vertices.add(new Point(100, -100, 100));
            
                    polygons.add(new Polygon(new ArrayList<>(), Color.RED));
                    polygons.get(1).vertices.add(new Point(100, 100, -100));
                    polygons.get(1).vertices.add(new Point(-100, 100, -100));
                    polygons.get(1).vertices.add(new Point(-100, -100, -100));
                    polygons.get(1).vertices.add(new Point(100, -100, -100));

                    polygons.add(new Polygon(new ArrayList<>(), Color.BLUE));
                    polygons.get(2).vertices.add(new Point(100, 100, 100));
                    polygons.get(2).vertices.add(new Point(-100, 100, 100));
                    polygons.get(2).vertices.add(new Point(-100, 100, -100));
                    polygons.get(2).vertices.add(new Point(100, 100, -100));
        
                    polygons.add(new Polygon(new ArrayList<>(), Color.GREEN));
                    polygons.get(3).vertices.add(new Point(-100, -100, 100));
                    polygons.get(3).vertices.add(new Point(-100, -100, -100));
                    polygons.get(3).vertices.add(new Point(100, -100, -100));
                    polygons.get(3).vertices.add(new Point(100, -100, 100));
            
                    polygons.add(new Polygon(new ArrayList<>(), Color.YELLOW));
                    polygons.get(4).vertices.add(new Point(100, 100, 100));
                    polygons.get(4).vertices.add(new Point(100, -100, 100));
                    polygons.get(4).vertices.add(new Point(100, -100, -100));
                    polygons.get(4).vertices.add(new Point(100, 100, -100));

                    polygons.add(new Polygon(new ArrayList<>(), Color.ORANGE));
                    polygons.get(5).vertices.add(new Point(-100, 100, 100));
                    polygons.get(5).vertices.add(new Point(-100, -100, 100));
                    polygons.get(5).vertices.add(new Point(-100, -100, -100));
                    polygons.get(5).vertices.add(new Point(-100, 100, -100));
            
                    double heading = Math.toRadians(x[0]);
                    Matrix3 headingTransform = new Matrix3(new double[] {
                            Math.cos(heading), 0, -Math.sin(heading),
                            0,1,0,
                            Math.sin(heading), 0, Math.cos(heading)
                    });
            
                    double pitch = Math.toRadians(y[0]);
                    Matrix3 pitchTransform = new Matrix3(new double[] {
                            1, 0, 0,
                            0, Math.cos(pitch), Math.sin(pitch),
                            0, -Math.sin(pitch), Math.cos(pitch)
                    });
            
                    Matrix3 transform = headingTransform.multiply(pitchTransform);
            
                    g2.translate(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);
            
                    BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

                    double[] zBuffer = new double[img.getWidth() * img.getHeight()];

                    for (int q = 0; q < zBuffer.length; q++) {
                        zBuffer[q] = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
                    }
                            
                    for (Polygon polygon : polygons) {
                        Polygon transformedPolygon = new Polygon(new ArrayList<>(), polygon.color);
                        for(Point point : polygon.vertices) {
                    transformedPolygon.vertices.add(transform.transform(point));
                        }
                
                        double minX = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
                        double maxX = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
                        double minY = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
                        double maxY = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
                
                        for (Point point : transformedPolygon.vertices) {
                            minX = Math.min(minX, point.x);
                            maxX = Math.max(maxX, point.x);
                            minY = Math.min(minY, point.y);
                            maxY = Math.max(maxY, point.y);
                        }
                
                        minX = Math.max(-frame.getWidth()/2, minX);
                        maxX = Math.min(frame.getWidth(), maxX);
                        minY = Math.max(-frame.getHeight()/2, minY);
                        maxY = Math.min(frame.getHeight(), maxY);
                                    
                            for (int y = (int) minY; y <= maxY; y++) {
                                for (int x = (int) minX; x <= maxX; x++) {
                                    Point pixel = new Point(x, y, 0);
                                    if (transformedPolygon.isPointInsidePolygon(pixel)) {
                                        double depth = 0;
                                        for(Point point: transformedPolygon.vertices) {
                                            depth += point.z;
                                        }
                                        int zIndex = ((y + frame.getHeight()/2) * img.getWidth()) + x + frame.getWidth()/2;
                                        if (zBuffer[zIndex] < depth) {
                                            img.setRGB(x + frame.getWidth()/2, y + frame.getHeight()/2, transformedPolygon.color.getRGB());
                                            zBuffer[zIndex] = depth;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            } 
                        g2.drawImage(img, -frame.getWidth()/2, -frame.getHeight()/2, null); 
                    }
                }
            };
    
            renderPanel.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {
                Point mousePos = new Point(MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x,MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y, 0);
                Point lastMousePosition = new Point(0, 0, 0);
                @Override
                public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                    mousePos = new Point(MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x,MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y, 0);
                    x[0] += (mousePos.x - lastMousePosition.x);
                    y[0] -= (mousePos.y - lastMousePosition.y);
                    lastMousePosition.x = mousePos.x;
                    lastMousePosition.y = mousePos.y;
                    renderPanel.repaint();
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                    if (e.getButton() != MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
                        mousePos = new Point(MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x,MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y, 0);
                        lastMousePosition.x = mousePos.x;
                        lastMousePosition.y = mousePos.y;
                    }
                }
            });
    
            pane.add(renderPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    
            frame.setSize(600, 600);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
    class Point {
        double x;
        double y;
        double z;
        Point(double x, double y, double z) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.z = z;
        }
    }

    class Polygon {
        ArrayList<Point> vertices;
        Color color;
        Polygon(ArrayList<Point> verticies, Color color) {
            this.vertices = verticies;
            this.color = color;
        }

        boolean isPointOnLine(Point p, Point p1, Point p2) {
            if (p.x <= Math.max(p1.x, p2.x)
                    && p.x >= Math.min(p1.x, p2.x)
                    && (p.y <= Math.max(p1.y, p2.y)
                        && p.y >= Math.min(p1.y, p2.y))) {
                return true;
            }else {
                return false;
            }        
        }

        int direction(Point p, Point q, Point r) {
            return (int) ((q.y - p.y) * (r.x - q.x) - (q.x - p.x) * (r.y - q.y));
        }

        public boolean isPointInsidePolygon(Point point) {
            Point outsidePoint = new Point(99999, point.y,0);
            int intersections = 0;
            int i;
            for(i = 0; i < this.vertices.size(); i++) {
                Point sidePoint1 = this.vertices.get(i);
                Point sidePoint2 = this.vertices.get((i+1) % this.vertices.size());
        
                int d1 = direction(point, outsidePoint, sidePoint1);
                int d2 = direction(point, outsidePoint, sidePoint2);
                int d3 = direction(sidePoint1, sidePoint2, point);
                int d4 = direction(sidePoint1, sidePoint2, outsidePoint);
        
                if ((((d1 > 0 && d2 < 0) || (d1 < 0 && d2 > 0)) && ((d3 > 0 && d4 < 0) || (d3 < 0 && d4 > 0)))) {
                    intersections++;
                }   
            }
    
            if(intersections % 2 == 1) {
                if(intersections != 1 && intersections != 0) {
                    System.out.print(intersections);
                }
                return true;
            }else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    class Matrix3 {
        double[] values;
        Matrix3(double[] values) {
            this.values = values;
        }
        Matrix3 multiply(Matrix3 other) {
            double[] result = new double[9];
            for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
                for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                        result[row * 3 + col] += this.values[row * 3 + i] * other.values[i * 3 + col];
                    }
                }
            }
            return new Matrix3(result);
        }
        Point transform(Point v) {
    
            return new Point(
                v.x * values[0] + v.y * values[3] + v.z * values[6],
                v.x * values[1] + v.y * values[4] + v.z * values[7],
                v.x * values[2] + v.y * values[5] + v.z * values[8]
        
            );
        }
    }
```

I thought maybe I got my matricies values incorrect, but I checked them with several sources and they appear right.

Comment: Please post your code as text, not a link to text.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I would like to note that replacing this:

Matrix3 transform = headingTransform.multiply(pitchTransform);

with this:

Matrix3 transform = pitchTransform.multiply(headingTransform);

Fixes the x rotation, but ruins the y rotation.